# How to make a Radio button with the same properties of a Checkbox using jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, radio-button, dom-manipulation, html

My HTML code is

```
  <table>
    <tr><td><input type="checkbox"></td><td><input type="checkbox"></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="checkbox"></td><td><input type="checkbox"></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="checkbox"></td><td><input type="checkbox"></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="checkbox"></td><td><input type="checkbox"></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="checkbox"></td><td><input type="checkbox"></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="checkbox"></td><td><input type="checkbox"></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="checkbox"></td><td><input type="checkbox"></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="checkbox"></td><td><input type="checkbox"></td></tr>
   </table>
```

My JQuery code is   (Not written by me, Some Stackoverflow use helped me on it, i am thanking him)

```
     $('TABLE TBODY TR').each(function()     
      {       
       var lastd =    $(this).children('tr td:last').find('input:checkbox');    
       var parentlast =   lastd.parent();       
       lastd.remove();           
       parentlast.append("<input type='radio'>"); // want to add the same properties of the removed checkbox     
      });
```

Please someone help me.

Comment: Not that it *really* matters, but why do this? Based on people's expectations, you're going to confuse the heck out of them. (For example, if I see a checkbox, I expect to be able to select multiple items. If I see a radio button, I expect to only be able to select one.) Any reason why you are changing convention? I'm just curious.

Comment: Is there a reason that you can't just render an input of type `radio` instead?

Comment: My server generates all checkboxes in a Table,That is our requirement but in some cases we use last checkbox as Exclusive.That is why i want to do like that :-)

Comment: @JasCav:  While I normally advise against changing normal convention, what the OP is asking will probably not confuse the average user depending on his application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully this will solve your problem.

```
 $('TABLE TBODY TR').each(function()
    {  
    var lastd =    $(this).children('tr td:last').find('input:checkbox');  
     var parentlast =   lastd.parent();
      lastd.remove();     
      parentlast.append("<input type='radio'>");

    });
```

So basically it will find last checkbox remove it from the dom and than creat a new one

Comment: You are appending a radio button right, but how can i add the same radio button with the same properties like id, name of that checkbox to that Radio button

Comment: parentlast.append("<input type='radio' id='someID' name='joe'>");

Answer (score 2):

Well, I don't see why you would want to do this, but you could just make it become a radio button.

```
$('tr:last td:last input:checkbox').prop('type', 'radio');
```

(this example uses jQuery 1.6)

[JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZKZNW/)

**UPDATE:** As @kei correctly pointed out, this one won't work IE <9. So I created this one:

```
var $csekk=$('tr:last td:last input:checkbox'),
    $klon=$csekk.clone().attr('type', 'radio');

$csekk.after($klon).remove();
```

[JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZKZNW/3/)

This one basically clones the checkbox (to keep every attribute you might have had associated with it), change the clone into a radio, inserts it and removes the old one.

Comment: IE8 (I also tested with browser mode to IE7, it won't allow the change)

Comment: @kei Yes, you're right, thanks. Wrote a simple cloning instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a plugin and tutorial to customize radio buttons and checkboxes with jQuery, CSS and image sprites.

[Accessible, Custom Designed Checkbox and Radio Button Inputs Styled with CSS (and a dash of jQuery)](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/accessible_custom_designed_checkbox_radio_button_inputs_styled_css_jquery/)

Since you'd be using custom created sprites, you can simply make them look like anything you want.